# Pulling JSON dynamically

Tags: python, json

I'm new with working JSON in python. I have a command which gives the output in the following format:

```
  "members": [
    {
      "address": "axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:2541",
      "roles": [
        "qq-default",
        "Server1"
      ],
      "status": "Up"
    },
    {
      "address": "axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:2542",
      "roles": [
        "qq-default",
        "Server2"
      ],
      "status": "Up"
    },
    {
      "address": "axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:4011",
      "roles": [
        "qq-default",
        "Server3"
      ],
      "status": "Up"
    },
    {
      "address": "axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:19941",
      "roles": [
        "qq-default"
      ],
      "status": "Up"
    }
  ],
  "self-address": "axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:2542",
  "unreachable": []
}
```

I'm trying to pull only the address, server name (like Server1, Server2 etc and *enter none if nothing is present*) and the status (up/down) and store it in 3 different arrays.

I tried using the regex but when i try to pull the Server names, i end up with the error - `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` may be because of the spaces.

My code -

```
import json
json_file = source_jsonfile
with open(json_file) as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file
    for e in json_data: 
        for key, value in e.iteritems():
                print key, value
```

Using RegEx -

```
RIDResult = re.search('"qq-default",        (.*)      ],', status)
print (RIDResult.group())
```

Please clarify on how to get the 3 different data and store it into arrays.TIA.

Comment: For future questions, it's helpful to provide an example of the expected output as well as the input.

Comment: Sure, i'll keep that in mind. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want three separate arrays of the item elements, this gives you them:

```
address, role, status = (
    [i["address"] for i in json_data["members"]],
    [i["roles"][1] if len(i["roles"]) > 1 else None for i in json_data["members"]],
    [i["status"] for i in json_data["members"]],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I don't misunderstood your requirements then this will works fine with your json,I've created a json file with your json structure, load/parse and finally set it to `address`, `status` and `server_name` index as an array `tia`

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('members.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

#pprint(data)
tia = {
    'address':[],
    'server_name':[],
    'status':[]
}

for members in data['members']:
    tia['address'].append(members['address'])
    tia['status'].append(members['status'])
    try:
       a = members['roles'][1]
    except IndexError:
       a = None
    tia['server_name'].append(a)

print(tia)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @sdevgd glad it helps you somehow. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension, to iterate over each of the dict in `json_data['members']` and access server name from each of those dict `d` as `d['roles'][1] if len(d['roles'])>=2 else None`

```
>>> [(d['address'],d['roles'][1] if len(d['roles'])>=2 else None) for d in json_data['members']]
[('axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:2541', 'Server1'), ('axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:2542', 'Server2'), ('axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:4011', 'Server3'), ('axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:19941', None)]
```

To create 3 different lists from them, use `zip`

```
>>> addr, server, status = zip(*[(d['address'],d['roles'][1] if len(d['roles'])>=2 else None, d['status']) for d in json_data['members']])
>>> print(addr)
('axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:2541', 'axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:2542', 'axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:4011', 'axyz.tcp://app@10.10.10.10:19941')
>>> print(server)
('Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3', None)
>>> print(status)
('Up', 'Up', 'Up', 'Up')
```

Comment: `json_data = json.loads(status);`
`addr, server, statuss = zip(*[(d['address'],d['roles'][1] if len(d['roles'])>= 2 else None, d['status']) for d in str(json_data['members'])]);`
`print (addr);`   **TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str**  but we are not using string anywhere when calling the indicis.